# Overlap in C++ and Java data structures: stack "top" vs "peek"

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, stack

I often use the Stack data structure in both Java and C++. This is a standard data structure, very common in implementing many algorithms.

My question is (and the thing that drives me crazy) why does C++ use "top" as a function-name that returns the top-most element value without removing it, and Java uses "peek" as it's method name?

I know there is no standard for data structures, but hasn't computer science come far enough along that there should be a standard? Or am I just too much of a novice to know about a standard...

Do those of you that are professional programmers write your own data-structure libraries that adhere to a common interface across languages? That seems like the best thing to do, in my mind. I write code in C++, Java, Python, C, Perl, and PHP. I just don't see any other way but to write a custom interface for all of these languages. I like "peek", but is there any standard I should be aiming for?

Comment: In C++, `stack::top` returns the _top_ element of the stack, while in Java the `peek` function takes a _peek_ at the top element?

Comment: ok, I'm surprised at the hostility on this site. I guess its not the place for newbees and dumb questions. Sorry.

Comment: @dvanaria: Don't feel sorry. I think it was a find question. The point is, the question doesn't really have an answer. That's why the site sort of rejected it. But I'm flagging that comment as offensive, because it is.

Comment: This question has been searched/viewed 5k times over the past 9 years! seems like many people, especially those who are not multi-language programmers has been wondering about the same question! Sorry that some people are so aggressive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a custom interface just to make method names the same would be a colossal waste of time. What exactly would be the point? You wouldn't be able to easily copy-and-paste most code between the languages you've mentioned even with such a feature.

Personally, I don't like the name of the STL vector method push_back(). I would prefer if it were just called add(), for one thing it'd be less typing. It never occurred to me that I might change it, however. Doing so would just make my code less portable and less readable for others. Now, I suppose this could be done fairly easily with a pre-processor macro, but even that would be a waste of time in my mind.

Comment: If it were `add` instead of `push_back`, then `deque` couldn't conform to its interface.

Comment: But `add` could be to the front or the back or the middle, so the name has to indicate where the element is being added to.

Comment: Not necessarily. It all comes down to convention. It would work fine if everyone understood that add() meant at the end and addfront() meant the opposite.

My point being, the convention for method names is rather arbitrary and you just have to live with it.

Answer (score 4):

No there can't be, won't be, and never will be a standard. Anyway, both names are valid, and if you ask me, `top` makes more sense. Also, as @mimicocotopus says, it's not like having the same method names would let you copy paste code from one language to another. Also, languages like C++ and Java are very distinct, and support different features. If a standard had to use the lowest common denominator, it couldn't take advantage of all of the features of the language it was implemented in.

Anyway, remember what happened last time we standardized something? Cross browser compatibility and porting C code. It gives me shudders just to think of it.